# ROP on MIPS Doesn't Land Where Calculated

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, reverse-engineering, aslr, rop

I am working on exploiting an application on MIPS to further my knowledge of ROP chaining. The library I am trying to build a ROP chain is `libuClibc-0.9.30.3.so`. I found a gadget that I want to use using Ropper. The offset is marked to be, `0x0002a730` and the instructions that Ropper show are `lw $v1, 0x1c($sp); lw $ra, 0x24($sp); nop; jr $ra; addiu $sp, $sp, 0x28;` the way I understand it is, I add this offset address to the base address of `libuClibc-0.9.30.3.so` to get the actual instruction address. I ran `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` to find the base address of `libuClibc-0.9.30.3.so` as `0x2aab1000` I also ran the program numerous times listing `show proc mappings` in `gdb`and found that this address doesn't appear to change between executions of the application. So I am assuming that this application doesn't utilize ASLR I also believe this to be true due to the fact that `file` doesn't say the program was compiled with `PIE` enabled. Additionally, jumping to the location at `0x2aab1000 + 0x0002a730` is consistently the same, which all points to this conclusion. However, the instruction that gets executed is not the instruction I am intending to have executed when the code jumps to the location. Any pointers for things to double check or potential issues with my logic are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after talking to numerous people and playing around with Ghidra and a few top gadget finders. This appears to be a common occurrence and isn't actually surprising. I was able to find the gadget I was looking for through trial and error and calculating where the offset sent me relative to where I wanted to be.